# Merge Shipping methods and Payment methods in one checkout step

Tags: onepage-checkout, shipping-methods, payment-methods

### Is it possible in easy step to move payment selection form from payment_methods step into shipping_method step?

What I want to achieve is to display shipping methods, and after select one of them display payment methods under shipping methods - on the same step without hiding shipping methods step.

Comment: use One step check module rather then use this

Comment: I'm using default Magento Onepage Checkout but have problems with rendering payment template.

Comment: use Any Magento External module one step checkout

Comment: I don't want to buy someone's module. I want to write custom changes.

Comment: Yes I have solution.